# WHILE LOOP not working as intended in mysql PROCEDURE

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have 100 rows in table `tbl_master_sales` and an empty table `tbl_customer_sales`.When I use WHILE loop to insert data from `tbl_master_sales`to `tbl_customer_sales`,it only inserts 50 rows.However,it should have insert 100 rows taking two iteration of while loop.What may be my mistake in following PROCEDURE:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ROWPERROW()
BEGIN
    DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_master_sales INTO n;
    SET i=0;
    WHILE i<n DO 

        INSERT INTO tbl_customer_sales (id,card_number,customer_name,customer_phone,bill_no,item_code,division,section,department,item_name,store,promo_name,billdiscount_name,billqty,promo_amount,bill_discount_amount,loyaltyamount,net_amount) 
            SELECT id, card_number, customer_name, customer_mobile, billno, itemcode, division, section, department, itemname, store, promoname, billdiscountname, billqty, promoamount, billdiscountamount, loyaltyamount, netamount
              FROM tbl_master_sales
             WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                                FROM tbl_customer_sales 
                               WHERE id=tbl_master_sales.id) 
             LIMIT i,50;


        SET i = i + 50;
    END WHILE;
End;;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your procedure code logic but the reason for inserting only 50 rows could be the `NOT EXISTS` part shown below, which is restricting from inserting duplicate rows (or) filtering out the rest records.

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
SELECT 1 
FROM tbl_customer_sales 
WHERE id=tbl_master_sales.id)
```

Comment: yes I am using NOT EXISTS part for avoiding duplication.I need that part too and need to insert 50 records each per iteration.Actually I used cursor for it before but it has performance problem and when I use INSERT...SELECT to insert data it inserts in single bulk which hangs entire mysql for millions of data.However I need procedure that inserts around 1000 rows per second and doesn't hangs mysql.How can I accomplish this??please,do you have any idea?